# is the Django management command executed in a separate process?

Tags: python, django, shell

Django has many management commands. In addition, we can write our own commands.

What happens after I make a shell call `python manage.py XXX`?
Will the code be executed in a process that launched from the shell?
Or the shell process just communicates with the main Django process that executes the command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell starts a new process to run the Python interpreter.  The Python interpreter reads `manage.py` and executes it directly.  There's no such thing as "the main Django process".